# Try to insert into HashMap but compiler error: cannot assign to X because it's borrowed

Tags: rust

i try to do some simple stuff with Rust and Excel. At some point i want to create a HashMap with Key=Worksheet and Values=Rows. I'm using office crate to handle Excel.

Now i created the following code:

```
let mut workSheets: HashMap<String, Rows> = HashMap::new();
let mut range: Range;

    for conf in config.supa{
        range = excel.worksheet_range(&conf.worksheet).unwrap_or_else(|err|{
            panic!("The Config-File contains worksheets, which are not present in your Excel-File. Notice that names must match exactly. Error: {}", err);
        });

        let _option = workSheets.insert(conf.worksheet, range.rows());
    }
```

This code gives me the following error on the "range" variable inside the for-loop:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `range` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:45:9
   |
45 |         range = excel.worksheet_range(&conf.worksheet).unwrap_or_else(|err|{
   |         ^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `range` occurs here
...
49 |         let _option = workSheets.insert(conf.worksheet, range.rows());
   |                       -----------------------------------------------
   |                       |                                 |
   |                       |                                 borrow of `range` occurs here
   |                       borrow later used here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0506`.
error: could not compile `supa_importer` due to previous error
```

Even with reading [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html) again & again, I don't get it. How can I solve this in a Rust way!?

Comment: I added complete compiler message. Before it was just the output of rust-analyzer.

Comment: Don't use the `office` crate. That's a (shameless, I might add) name-squatting crate that is nothing but a long-outdated version of `calamine`. So use that if you only need reading support; use `rust_xlsxwriter` if you need writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `range.rows()` it takes `range` by reference. See [here](https://docs.rs/office/latest/office/struct.Range.html#method.rows) the `&self` argument. It is unfeasible to store `Rows` in your `HashMap`, because it does not own the underlying data (your `range` variable owns the data you want to access through the `Rows` iterator). A better solution would be to store `Range` instead of `Rows` in your `HashMap` (that way the entry of the `HashMap` would own the data) and call `.rows()` on a value when you need it. I.e.:

```rust
use office::{Excel, Range, Rows};

use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut workSheets: HashMap<String, Range> = HashMap::new();
    
    for conf in config.supa{
        let range = excel.worksheet_range(&conf.worksheet).unwrap_or_else(|err|{
            panic!("The Config-File contains worksheets, which are not present in your Excel-File. Notice that names must match exactly. Error: {}", err);
        });

        workSheets.insert(conf.worksheet, range).unwrap();
    }
}
```

You can then access `Rows` like this, for example:

```rust
workSheet["foo"].rows()
```

Answer (score 2):

First, use `calamine` instead of `office`. Reason explained in comment. Let's get that out of the way first.

---

On with the actual error: Jonas already provided a solution, so I'm going to explain "the why" some more and what to watch out for.

The key is to always pay close attention to whether a type has ownership of **all** its data (in Rust lingo, "owned type"), or whether it holds references to other data. An easy way to tell whether a type is an "owned type" is to check its type signature for lifetimes (a type parameter that starts with a tick, often `'a`).

Owned types are the easiest to work with, because they contain (a.k.a. own) their own copy of data and are not associated with (a.k.a. contain references to) anything else.

However often you don't want to always copy the memory (clone) the underlying data, such as the case with most iterators. Since you are holding a reference to some piece of data elsewhere, that piece of data must not be freed while you have the reference.

---

So if you take a look at the signature of [`Rows` struct](https://docs.rs/calamine/latest/calamine/struct.Rows.html) (which you obtain via the `Range::rows` function), you see the aforementioned `'a` in its type parameters, which makes sense because it's an iterator on the data owned by a `Range` struct. If you want to store this struct, you are going to hold a long-lasting reference to the `Range` struct that it references, which is exactly your error here.

In each iteration of your loop, you are storing the `Range` in the `range` variable, and storing a reference to this `Range`'s underlying data (in the form of a `Rows` struct) in a `HashMap`. But in the next iteration, the `range` variable is reassigned, which means its old underlying data is freed, invalidating all references pointing to it. Dangling reference is a very common bug in non-memory safe languages, and is not allowed in safe Rust, hence your error "cannot assign to `range` because it is borrowed".

If you are curious, try moving the `let range = ...` inside the loop and observe how the error changes. It might make a bit more sense to you that way.